# Replace variable value with new change/increment value in different file using gradle/groovy task?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am trying to replace the specific variable value in my version.gradle file which consist lots of other variable with new/incremneted value using gradle/groovy

Below is my version.gradle file in below format

```
ext {
  def planName = System.env.bamboo_buildPlanName
  //println planName
  testversion="1.1.1.49"
  if (planName != null && project.hasProperty('abc')) {
    cAVersion = "${crversion}.${System.env.bamboo_buildNumber}"
    //println clVersion
    } else if (project.hasProperty("def")){
    cAVersion = "${crversion}"}
    else if (project.hasProperty("ghf")){
    cAVersion = "${crversion}"
    }else {
    cAVersion = ""
    }   
  ghkVersion = project.findProperty("abcVersion") ?: '1.0.8.66-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Below is my code which I am trying to use to increment/change the value of crversion from 1.1.1.49 ----> 1.1.1.50 so everytime this will increment +1 last number(49-50 and so on) and then replace the value of crversion variable with new value

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/version.gradle"

task incrementrevsion{
    def file = new File('version.gradle')
    def v = crversion
    println v
    String minor=v.substring(v.lastIndexOf('.')+1) //get last digit
    int m=minor.toInteger()+1                      //increment
    println m
    String major=v.substring(0,v.lastIndexOf("."));       //get the beginning without period(.)
    println major
    String s=file.text.replace("crversion='$crversion '","crversion='"+major+ "." +m+"'")
    println s
    file.setText(s) //replace the build file's text
}
```

After that I will use two more gradle task which will commit the file and push it to version control.

1) I am able to update/increment the value successfully in other file but if value of crversion='1.2.3' in format if value is crversion = "1.2.3" then it is not working.why?

Comment: Is there really a space after the version? `crversion='$crversion '`

Comment: Yes there is a space crversion = "1.2.3" )both side of equal)?

Comment: Then this example/code is wrong on three places.  Have a very close look at what you are replacing there: 1) your place `'` instead of `"`.  2) your replace with _no_ whitespace around the `=` 3) you have a trailing space before the last `'`

Comment: The above example is with a='1.2.3' NOT a = "1.2.3"

Comment: But in your comment and your `version.gradle` you wrote `"` - in your replacment function you use `'` and you have a trailing space before `'`.  Therefor my guess is, that you just see no swap, because of searching for the wrong thing and if you can't help them, because humans change this file too, you are better off replacing with a regexp instead.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't work because in your code `file.text.replace("crversion='$crversion '","crversion='"+major+ "." +m+"'")` you just replace something like `'version_number'` with other version literally.

You do not deal with the case like `"version_number"`.
A silly fix  `file.setText(s.replace("crversion=\"$crversion \"","crversion='"+major+ "." +m+"'"))`, considering performance is not the concern in gradle scripts.

Comment: this is not working version number is in this format crversion = "1.2.3" (space both side of equal)